# How are strokes stored in the Goodnotes file format?

Tags: file-format, ios

I have been trying to reverse engineer the .goodnotes file format ([a note taking app](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/goodnotes-5/id1444383602) for iOS devices) and so far have discovered this:

- A .goodnotes file is simply a zip archive, [an example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23l085kz6kgbl2j/Strokes.goodnotes?dl=0) extracted has the following hierarchy:

```
attachments/
    1AF85389-413A-4C21-8EF5-C0603033CBF8
index.attachments.pb
index.events.pb
index.notes.pb
index.search.pb
notes/
    30F8BBBA-710B-4BEC-A90B-49DFCEF05035
search/
    1AF85389-413A-4C21-8EF5-C0603033CBF8
thumbnail.jpg
```

- It is likely the strokes are stored within the notes/ directory and separated by page (if an empty page is added the corresponding notes file is zero bytes)
- The files named by ID could be binary protobuf files, though I'm not sure and all efforts to reverse engineer the protobuf schema has failed

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Sharing exactly what you've tried and ruled out might help others avoid wasting time ?

Comment: I wrote about it https://www.reddit.com/r/RELounge/comments/jvutht/goodnotes_5_files_discussion/

Comment: I just hopped in this thread because I was searching for a possibility to reuse GoodNotes Files on my Linux Machine ... The [reddit-Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/RELounge/comments/jvutht/goodnotes_5_files_discussion/ggky8xf/) referenced above ends around March 2021 with no real conclusion and has been archived in the meantime. There is an IMHO related question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054282/1008428) from July '18 but no real progress as far as I could find. Does anyone have news on this subject?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I understand it takes some getting used to, but this is no forum. We are a Q&A site and that means no discussion outside of comments (which, I get that, you cannot yet write on account of your reputation points). So I converted your "question" into a comment as it _is_ commentary.